# GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

All working BUT

only giving 100 security groups, I have many more in AD

Is the API limited to just 100 objects.

What comes through appears to be random, ie those missing groups look identical in AD

Answer (score 1):

I came across the @odata.nextlink delta when looking through the "Change Tracking" section. My code was ignoring the nextlink.

Many thanks for pointing out the OData query $top=999 that may fix my issue although the nextlink will be a more exhaustive solution.

Many thanks indeed for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$top=999 for example to get more than 100.

Or you can use the pagination functionality: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging